# How to install PyQT4 and what are the practical differences between PyQT4 and PyQT5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am about to start developing using PyQT, but there seem to exist two versions. Which one should I go for?

Also, I cannot seem to be able to install *either*, using `pip install PyQt4` I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking PyQt4
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt4
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PyQt4
Storing complete log in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Log says:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/projects/pyqt-test-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/user/projects/pyqt-test-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/user/projects/pyqt-test-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1085, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/home/user/projects/pyqt-test-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 265, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pyqt4
```

`pip search pyqt` lists at least `PyQt4` so it gives me the impression that the package is in the list:

```
PyQt4                     - Python bindings for the Qt cross platform GUI toolkit
```

Is there any official way to install this thing on generic Linux? How do I do that?

Answer (score 14):

I emailed rivercomputing:

> If I try to installed PyQt4 via pip, I get the following message:
>
> $ pip install PyQt4
>   Downloading/unpacking PyQt4
>     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt4
>   No distributions at all found for PyQt4
>   Storing complete log in /home/jon/.pip/pip.log
>
> However, if I search for PyQt4, the package is clearly there:
>
> $ pip search PyQt4
>   ...
>   ...
>   PyQt4     - Python bindings for the Qt cross platform GUI toolkit
>   python-qt - Python compatibility wrapper for Qt Bindings
>   ...
>   ...
>
> The pypi page for this package is also reachable
>   (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt4/4.10.3); however, I did notice 
>   that
>   the download statistics are at 0.
>
> How can I install PyQt4 via pip?

And got the following "not constructive" reply:

> You can't.

Answer (score 4):

I think to install **PyQt4**, first of all you need **sip**. Information can be available from the **riverbank computing** website.

or if you are using Ubuntu/debian, you can get easily from the repositories :

> sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools

Comment: A required dependency 'pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)' is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. In the end I downloaded SIP and PyQt from [riverbankcomputing.com](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), and installed them with:

```
python configure.py
make
make install
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: I don't see how this doesn't answer [my] question? I ask at the end of my question post -- "is there any official way [to install] on generic Linux? How do I do that?". This is an honest attempt to describe a way to install it, whether `make & make install` can be considered "official" is at least debatable. What am I missing?